# Как пропустить аргумент в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я имею такой код

```
@client.command(aliases= ['vc'])
async def __voice_settings(ctx, command, *, name, member: discord.Member = None):
try:
    if vc_exist(ctx=ctx) == False:
        await ctx.send("У вас нету своего кастомного канала.")
    elif vc_exist(ctx=ctx) == True:
        vc_id = get_vc_id(ctx=ctx)
        vc_take = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id = vc_id)
        if command == 'название':
            await vc_take.edit(name=name)
            await ctx.send("Вы успешно изменили название канала.")
        elif command == 'добавить':
            if member == 'все':
                roletake = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 847866866612305920)
                await vc_take.set_permissions(roletake, connect = True)
                await ctx.send("Вы успешно разрешили доступ к подключению всем.")
            else:
                who = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id = member.id)
                await vc_take.set_permissions(who, connect = True)
                await ctx.send(f"Вы успешно разрешили доступ к подключению пользователю {member}")
        elif command == 'удалить':
            if member == 'все':
                roletake = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 847866866612305920)
                await vc_take.set_permissions(roletake, connect = False)
                await ctx.send("Вы успешно запретили доступ к подключению всем")
            else:
                who = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id = member.id)
                await vc_take.set_permissions(who, connect = False)
                await ctx.send("Вы успешно удалили доступ к подключению")
except Exception as e:
    await ctx.send("Неожиданная ошибка.")
    print(f"[ - ] Unexpected error | member.id {ctx} \n\n {e}")
```

При использовании команды `.vc добавить @user1` оно, как не странно, выдает мне ошибку. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы команда выше работала, но при этом работали и другие команды: `.vc название Это Крутое Название!`

Единственный вариант, который я хотел попробовать - это использовать переменную `name` вместо `member`, но не знаю как ей присвоить значение discord.Member, при этом оставив его изначальное значение. Потому что без присвоения я не могу использовать `member.id`, чтобы получить id.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать параметры по умолчанию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом случае просто воспользуйтесь функцией [**`discord.utils.get`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.utils.get), но в качестве свойства объекта участника используйте не `id`, а форму упоминания `mention`, которая при упоминании будет содержаться в `name`

```py
@client.command(aliases= ['vc'])
async def __voice_settings(ctx, command, *, name):
           ...
    elif command == 'добавить':
        if member == 'все':
                ...
        else:
            who = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, mention=name)
                ...
```

Если такого участника нет, или он был упомянут некорректно (просто рандомный текст), `who` примет значение `None` и его можно будет обработать через `if who == None`